# mod_rewrite to specific url in laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Laravel. I added  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` to my htaccess file.
Now I wanna redirect all URLs to the specific landing page. So I added `RewriteRule (.*)$ /land [L,R=301]` 
But my site does not load after this change. I couldn't handle it with [L , R] attributes.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /newsletter [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`
```

is there any help?